# How to read data from multiple entries in .NET MAUI XAML by pressing 1 button

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a question. I'm writing a simple .NET MAUI application in which I would like to read data from multiple entries. My XAML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:WijnApp.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:WijnReviewViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WijnApp.Models"
             x:Class="WijnApp.Views.WijnReviewPagina"
             Title="WijnReviewPagina">

    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="4" VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Label
            Text="Please fill in your review here. To confirm: press enter"
        ></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="ReviewText"
            TextChanged="ReviewTextChanged"
            Completed="ReviewTextCompleted"/>

        <Label
            Text="Is de wijn licht of stevig?"
            BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=SmaakprofielLichtOfStevig}"
        ></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference SmaakprofielLichtOfStevig},
                              Path=Value,
                              StringFormat='{0:F2}'}" />
        <Slider x:Name="SmaakprofielLichtOfStevig"
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="10"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label
            Text="Is de wijn soepel of tanninerijk?"
            BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=SmaakprofielSoepelOfTannineRijk}"
        ></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference SmaakprofielSoepelOfTannineRijk},
                              Path=Value,
                              StringFormat='{0:F2}'}" />
        <Slider x:Name="SmaakprofielSoepelOfTannineRijk"
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="10"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label
            Text="Is de wijn droog of zoet?"
            BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=SmaakprofielDroogOfZoet}"
        ></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference SmaakprofielDroogOfZoet},
                              Path=Value,
                              StringFormat='{0:F2}'}" />
        <Slider x:Name="SmaakprofielDroogOfZoet"
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="10"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label
            Text="Is de wijn rond of fris?"
            BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=SmaakprofielRondOfFris}"
        ></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference SmaakprofielRondOfFris},
                              Path=Value,
                              StringFormat='{0:F2}'}" />
        <Slider x:Name="SmaakprofielRondOfFris"
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="10"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label
            Text="Wat denkt u dat 1 fles van deze wijn kost in euro's? Indien u wilt bevestigen: druk op enter"
        ></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="GeschattePrijsPerFles"
            TextChanged="EstimatedPricePerBottleChanged"
            Completed="EstimatedPricePerBottleCompleted"/>

        <Label
            Text="Wat heeft u over voor 1 fles van deze wijn in euro's? Indien u wilt bevestigen: druk op enter"
        ></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="HoeveelOverVoor1Fles"
            TextChanged="HowMuchToSpendPerBottleChanged"
            Completed="HowMuchToSpendPerBottleCompleted"/>

        <Label
            Text="Op een schaal van 0 tot 10: hoe zou u deze wijn beoordelen?"
            BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Score}"
        ></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference Score},
                              Path=Value,
                              StringFormat='{0:F2}'}" />
        <Slider x:Name="Score"
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="10"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        <Button Text="Save"
                Clicked="SaveReview"/>

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

As you can see, I have a button with the text 'Save' and a SaveReview clicked event. My client hates it when he has to press the enter key on the keyboard after filling in each entry field, so I thought I should read and handle all the entry fields when the user presses the 'Save' button. I have 2 questions about this approach:

- What is the most elegant way of doing this? I read about loading XAML at runtime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/runtime-load , but this not recommended.
- With this aproach, I doubt if it is possible for the user to see their input in real time. Am I right about this?

Hopefully you guys want to help me out. Coming from Python Django development, I recon I still have to learn a lot.

Thank you in advance!

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/runtime-load -> this is not recommended

Comment: either use data binding, or simply read the value of each entry using `MyEntryName.Text` in code.  This should have nothing to do with "runtime load".

Comment: 1) *"I doubt if it is possible for the user to see their input in real time."* - why do you doubt? Whenever he presses a key, whatever entry is selected will show that character. 2) *"My client hates it when he has to press the enter key on the keyboard after filling in each entry field"* - When he presses enter, doesn't it go to next entry field automatically? Isn't that easier than using mouse to move to next field?

Comment: You can accept one of them as the best answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

either use data binding, or refer to each entry by name

```
protected void SaveReview(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var v1 = HoeveelOverVoor1Fles.Text;
    var v2 = GeschattePrijsPerFles.Text;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! This works like a charm. Sometimes I overcomplicate things and this is an clear example

Answer (score 0):

IF they don't like to press buttons, why don't you save whenever they leave the field, using the unfocused event?

```xml
<Entry
    x:Name="ReviewText"
    Completed="ReviewTextCompleted"
    TextChanged="ReviewTextChanged">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior Command = "{Binding SaveReviewCommand}" EventName="Unfocused" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```